# Why didn't new user lose rep via downvote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes

The other day I came across a question. The user has 6 reputation, but has only the one question, which has a score of 0 and is a

> Member since today

I checked the vote counts, and noticed that it had one upvote and one downvote. The thing that suprised me, was that the user doesn't appear to have lost 2 reputation from the downvote. Is this a problem, or will the reputation loss happen later, or is this something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Likely the downvote happened before the upvote - meaning, 1 - 2 = 1 (because you don't get less than 1), then 1 + 5 = 6. The order of the votes matters.

Comment: If the upvote were first, it would be 1 + 5 = 6, then 6 - 2 = 4.

Comment: Oh, thank you @Oded I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Oded. After his idea, I checked the profile page of the user, and yes: The downvote happened *before* the upvote.

Proof:

[image]

Comment: strange way to calculate the rep... isn't the server supposed to make a total with every vote ? no matter the order ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier No, it happens sequentially.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier "supposed to"... Where did you read that? IIRC it's said straight in the help center

Comment: @Patrice Well I thought it would be the logical way, don't you think the reel rep of this user is 4 and not 6 ? I do. Then where is it written straight in the help center ? I can't find it even searching for it.